# ERROR:Exception in request: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://********:80 refused

Tags: java, database, amazon-web-services, soap, soapui

When I use SoapUI for testing SOAP project, I met an error, it pop up ERROR:Exception in request: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://(my website):80 refused. Does anyone know why this happen? I actually post my web app and database to AWS, those are on cloud now. Anyone met similar before? Thanks

Comment: Without knowing why you where refused, nope. It might need a certificate, a token for the connection, a different port than 80 (which is not necessary as `http:` mean the port 80). What is the response ? Have you check the url of your backend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port : 80 is used by default on some programmes. It is probably in use already. 
Try changing to a different port. e.g. port:81

Answer (score 0):

If you go through a proxy, try to disable it : 
[Looks at the soapui toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXgqj.png)